# In Help and Improvement, closing the question does not remove the edit button

Tags: bug, review-queues, closed-questions, help-improvement

Pretty easy to duplicate

1. Find a question in the H&I queue that should be closed
2. Open the question in a separate window and close the question
3. Refresh the H&I page

You'll see the following

[image]

Visible here
https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/14392893

If the item is not reviewable, shouldn't the edit button be removed?

Comment: The item is not reviewable, but that does not mean you cannot edit it. The edit just won't count as a completed review task. Makes sense to me.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yeah, but that's not clear to the user

Comment: Why not? It is not reviewable, but still editable. Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: I guess the question I have is why H&I marks closed questions as unreviewable.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, historically it has been a bone of contention that the only way to remove a question from the H&I that could not be made on-topic by the community, was to flag it as VLQ. VLQ flagging a question that is not actually VLQ is not a good option. I imagine that this was put into place so that users had another method of removing the question from the queue.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I suppose that's not the worst justification, although it still seems a bit off. OTOH, it's not like there's any real lack of questions in the queue.

Comment: What if the user just closed his question, but undeletes it later on? It will be unedited and unclear.

Comment: @dev closure !== deletion

Comment: For reference, even though I disagree that it is a bug, or should be changed, I have yet to vote on this question