# On 'Help and Improvement' Review what should I do when I face a post that can be edited only by the owner?

Tags: support, review-queues, help-improvement

Example: if there's missing code/info that only the OP can provide.

Comment: Then it shouldn't have entered the H&I queue.  You can shuffle it on yet another garbage pile but this crap has already occupied too much time and energy with nothing to show for it.  A downvote and a close vote gets the job done much quicker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the queue all you can do is use the "very low quality" flag to send it back to the triage queue, so that they can hopefully triage the post *correctly* this time and flag it for closure.

You can also go to the post itself and vote/flag it for closure for an appropriate reason, to help speed things along by sending it directly to the close queue.

Comment: Every time I did this I just ended up with a bunch of "declined - a moderator found no evidence for your flag" on my profile. I'm not overly worried about that *as such*, but it seems that this is not the correct thing to do(?)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker _Theoretically_ it is the correct thing to do. Problem is, flagging it puts it in another review queue... and that queue messes up like the Triage queue did earlier. Which is why I much prefer Servy's second option - open in another tab and VTC. And if you're feeling helpful, add a comment explaining to the OP how to improve the question.

Comment: _Correct_ triaging is a big part of the problem.  On back-clicking after triaging a post I see many "Requires Editing" reviews for questions containing no code where I have reviewed "unclear what you're asking".  There may be a misunderstanding among, hopefully novice, triagers' that "Requires Editing" just returns the question to the OP without knowing that the response creates work for the H&I queue.  A change to the Triage top bar help to delete "the author or" would make it clearer **that someone other than the author will be forced to look at the question.**

Comment: Maybe it should be flagged as off-topic "Questions...must include the desired behavior...and the shortest code necessary"?

Comment: @freestock.tk The close reason you should use will vary based on the specifics of the question, which is why I didn't name a specific reason to begin with.  Any of them may be appropriate for any given question.

Comment: Be careful what you are flagging for Low Quality. This flag is very subjective. Nearly all my declined flags are based on the H&I-Queue.

Comment: To expand an important point that @MarkFitzgerald said: the "(more)" text in the Triage queue, *which novice triagers probably look to for guidance*, explicitly defines the **"Requires editing" category** as being *"for questions where edits **by the author** or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable"*, while the tooltip of the **"Requires editing" button** states that *"this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of editors"*. The former seems incorrect.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It's the only option the queue provides, and it's what the guidelines suggest, so there's really not much of any alternative.  I do realize that many mods don't understand the review system, the guidelines given for flagging, etc., but it's not like there are other choices.

Comment: @lfurini It is incorrect, which is why I mention in the answer that the cause of this is improper reviews in triage.

Comment: The problem is that VLQ is for [obvious, unarguable garbage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/2336725).  I usually interpret that to be spam, a foreign language, or a cat walking on a keyboard.  Help and Improvement usually ends up with things that should have been closed, but not bad enough for VLQ.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker et al You may find [this discussion](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/969/2016/1/14) enlightening.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Since all VLQ flags for questions go into Triage, and Triage can do nothing more than mark Unsalvageable (i.e., Close), it's clear that this definition of VLQ is wrong on SO, and has been for years.

Comment: @Nathan According to shog, the VLQ flag should not be used in the H&I for anything that is not actually VLQ. Instead you should visit the question, downvote, close vote, and move on.

Comment: @TinyGiant: If you're referring to the linked answer, that's outdated, since it predates Triage/H&I, and cannot possibly be applied as-is. If you're referring to something else, please link it.

Comment: @Nathan I'm referring to the chat discussion between me and shog that I linked above.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I'm not really seeing a hardline "don't use the VLQ option" stance anywhere in that discussion. Just "understand how things work at low levels so you can be prepared for whatever results".

Comment: @Nathan Did you miss the part about what should be flagged as VLQ and what shouldn't? It doesn't change just because the post is in the H&I. If it is VLQ, flag it as VLQ. If it is not VLQ, but warrants closure, visit the question and vote to close it. At least that's what I got from all of that

Comment: @Nathan [Here is the answer which spurred on that chat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314663/4639281), as you can see it was basically the same discussion as is happening here. As well [closing a question invalidates the H&I review task](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338430/4639281)

Comment: I think its mainly fault of the button text: in Triage we have a button named 'unsalvageable' that sounds like 'not even the owner can rescue the question its so bad that it deserves the trashcan'. So when the question in focus is not that bad and can be fixed by the owner it isnt flagged with this button.

Comment: @Servy now I am banned :(. [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346020/2441442)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to remove a question from the Help and Improvement (H&I) queue:

### Editing the post

This will remove the question from the H&I queue and nothing else will happen. If the post is off-topic in its current state and no amount of editing from the community will make it on-topic, this is probably not a very good option to pick.

### Flagging as VLQ

This will remove the question from the H&I queue and one of the following will happen:

- If the question is still eligible for triage, it will be pushed back into triage. At this point it is very likely to be pushed back into the H&I by well meaning but unknowing reviewers.
- If the question is no longer eligible for triage, it will be pushed to a mod queue where moderators will review the flag as if you had flagged it in the wild. They have no way of knowing that the post was flagged from the H&I, and if the post isn't truly VLQ then you will get a declined flag and nothing else will happen to the post.

Either way, unless the post is truly VLQ, this isn't a very good option either.

### Closing the question

This will remove the question from the H&I queue and the question will be closed. A single close vote will not remove the question from the H&I queue, the question must be closed for this to happen. If we can get enough H&I reviewers on the same page about this then this will be the best option.

If you see a post in the H&I queue that is off-topic and no amount of editing from the community will make it on-topic, **flag it for closure or vote to close it if you have the privilege**, then skip the review and move on. If all goes well, everything will work itself out in the end.