# What is the official moderator statement about low quality flags in the Help and Improvement queue?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, help-improvement

After a long time I started reviewing in H&I again. Per [this advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343417/2441442) I flagged everything I would normally close as low quality.

Now I am banned:

[image: banned]

Looking at the flags:

- [How to separate datablocks and plot in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004829/how-to-separate-datablocks-and-plot-in-python) (Maybe some borderline case. Don't know enough about [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992434/class-not-found-after-renaming-folders (Lacks MCVE)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977020/encode-decode-issue-while-working-on-cross-platform (Too broad, lacks MCVE)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973114/view-pager-like-android-instagram-posting-page (Too broad, lacks MCVE)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012641/php-jquery-form-ajax-file-upload-error (Lacks MCVE)

I also have had this discussion in the meta post linked above:

> Be careful what you are flagging for Low Quality. This flag is very
>   subjective. Nearly all my declined flags are based on the H&I-Queue

[- me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343416/on-help-and-improvement-review-what-should-i-do-when-i-face-a-post-that-can-be/343417#comment445828_343417)

> It's the only option the queue provides, and it's what the guidelines
>   suggest, so there's really not much of any alternative. I do realize
>   that many mods don't understand the review system, the guidelines
>   given for flagging, etc., but it's not like there are other choices.

[– Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343416/on-help-and-improvement-review-what-should-i-do-when-i-face-a-post-that-can-be/343417#comment445830_343417)

So is my ban incorrect, or have I done something wrong? I just wanted to help.

In which queue do these flags go? Elected moderators?

What is the official statement about Low Quality in Help & Improvement?

Comment: Those questions should be closed; one of them already is.

Comment: IMHO the people who said *requires editing* in triage for all of those should be review banned, not you.  I can see why the VLQ flags were declined but you should have never had to flag them in the first place.  I know it stinks and it really isn't what you want to hear but I would just stay away from H&I until Stack Overflow gets triage working right. (don't hold your breath, it has been over a year asking them to change one line in the guidance and it hasn't happened).

Comment: Well, that "VLQ" flag link in the H&I queue is very counterproductive. As you already noticed, VLQ has a very strict meaning and providing only that option directly in the queue leads to this situation here. That queue should use the normal "Vote to Close" dialog to avoid incorrect flags.

Comment: @NathanOliver he didn't "flag them", Christian just wanted to signal that they weren't fit for the H&I queue, and guess what's the only way to do that? [\*points towards Shog flow chart...\*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png)

Comment: @Braiam Ugh. Clicking VLQ in H&I sends the question back to Triage - to the same reviewers who let these Unsalvageable things through in the first place. What could POSSIBLY go wrong?!

Comment: @Braiam What are you talking about?  The OP did flag them: *I flagged everything I would normally close as low quality.*

Comment: @NathanOliver \*points towards the flow chart again\* What's the only way that items in the H&I queue gets kicked towards triage? Flagging as VLQ/

Comment: @Braiam I'm not understanding what you are trying to say.  The OP did flag the post.  You telling me he didn't doesn't make sense

Comment: @NathanOliver He's signaling that those posts aren't unfit for the H&I queue. What's the only way to do that?

Comment: @NathanOliver Braiam tells you, I have flagged the post because of [insert his comment]

Comment: Yes, you flagged the post to get them out of H&I, which is what you should have.  The problem with that is they really don't fit the VLQ flag but that is the only flag SO gives you.  I'm still not sure what @Braiam is trying to say.

Comment: @NathanOliver [VLQ is the only possible flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdst3.jpg)

Comment: I know that.  That's why I told you to stay away as the only tool they give you is the wrong one.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Triage has lots of reviewers, and a good number of them know better than what the guidance text says. *Any* post that gets incorrectly sent to H&I *will* eventually undergo a correct Triage review if H&I reviewers keep flagging it as VLQ (these flags get disputed when Triage says that a post Looks OK or Requires Editing, so don't worry about declined flags).

Comment: @dorukayhan Your optimism [has not been borne out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344505/reviewing-triage-queue-failed-audit-for-unknown-to-me-reason)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The original meaning of "Very Low Quality" is that something [needs to be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/168333).

Shog9 wrote about the VLQ flag in the H&I queue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/812149), where he implies that this meaning is less strict for the VLQ flag in H&I. In H&I, the VLQ flag sends a question back to Triage, from where it *may* get deleted.   Although Shog9 expresses that VLQ is something different from "needs to be closed", he seems to reluctantly admit that is used that way in H&I for practical purposes.

So in H&I, the VLQ flag means "*may* need to be deleted. Somebody have a second look at it".

The problem, of course, is that the *somebody* to have a second look at it is the Triage review queue. The very same queue that these questions should not have escaped in the first place.

Your flag ban is wrong and should be lifted. The reviewers who let these things out of Triage should be review-banned instead.

As a practical note, since you can't rely on the VLQ flag in H&I working properly, just open the Unsalvageable questions outside the queue and VTC from there. I've been doing that for a long time.

Comment: So declined means, some of our robo reviewers pressed edit again?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yes. ["Requires Editing"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15651436) or perhaps even "Looks OK" :-(

Comment: This must be a bad joke.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt A lot of the "reviewing" in Triage is a bad joke :-(

Comment: This whole VLQ system for questions doesn't make any sense. The flag should do the exact same on questions as it does on answers - take it to the low quality posts queue where people can recommend deletion. Sending questions that are flagged to a queue (Triage) where people can't vote to delete the post but can only flag/vote to close defeats the whole purpose of the VLQ flag, which is meant to say "this should be deleted".

Comment: @Keiwan On Stack Overflow, questions no longer go into Low Quality because they go into Triage. And if it gets closed in Triage it _may_ get deleted. Yes, that's wrong, but that's the way it works right now.

Comment: I'm guessing that when a VLQ flag sends an item back from H&I (where it may have a special meaning) to Triage, it won't be obvious to the people there that this has happened, so even if they are paying perfect attention, they won't be aware of the flag's special meaning...

Comment: imo triage needs a fundamental overhaul. What gets passed through there as ok is entirely unacceptable a lot of times. Making flag declines hinge on that is madness.

Comment: This is incorrect because if a post is flagged as VLQ, but marked as Looks OK or is edited from within the queue, the flag is marked as disputed. If it was declined, that means a moderator reviewed it. If a post is in the H&I and is flagged as VLQ but no longer meets the criteria for entry into triage, it is sent to a moderator queue where a moderator will review the flag and either mark it helpful or decline it. Moderators are not shown whether or not the post was flagged from the H&I.

Comment: As a side note, your last sentence is the correct course of action because closing a question _will_ remove it from the H&I and _won't_ just send it back to triage where it will undoubtedly be reviewed incorrectly again. If you know it is unsalvageable, why send it back to triage? Just flag / vote to close it and put it in the correct queue, which is the close vote review queue

Comment: Related feature request: [Add close option to the “Help and Improvement” queue to avoid cluttering flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297489/add-close-option-to-the-help-and-improvement-queue-to-avoid-cluttering-flags) (Oh, and as a not-so-subtle plug, my [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script / browser extension includes a client-side implementation of it.)

Answer (score 5):

**Quit worrying about what everyone else is going to do in the Help and Improvement queue.**

The main motivator for people flagging these review tasks as VLQ is that they want to remove the review task from the Help and Improvement queue. The reason that you want to do that is that you don't want someone else to have to review it.

### STAPPIT!

You think it's unsalvageable but it doesn't actually qualify as VLQ (meaning that it is complete unarguable garbage that the community cannot delete fast enough)? Step out of the queue, visit the question, and flag or vote for closure. This will put the question in the close vote queue where users with the close vote privilege will review it for closure.

Triage is broken, horribly so. **If you know that pushing the post back into triage is a pointless endeavor, why do it?** Put it in the close vote queue where it belongs and move on. Closure of a question will remove it from the Help and Improvement queue, and there is still a possibility that someone may come along who actually can fix the question.

Also keep in mind that only moderators can decline flags. Post flagged as VLQ that are reviewed as Looks OK or are edited from within the queue mark the flags as disputed. If you flag a question in the Help and Improvement queue as VLQ, but it no longer fits the criteria to enter triage, it will be sent to a moderator queue. When this happens, there is no indication that the post was flagged in the Help and Improvement queue, so the moderator will review it just as they would any other VLQ flag.

That said, if you see a question in the Help and Improvement queue that is complete unarguable garbage that the community cannot delete fast enough, don't hesitate to flag it as VLQ. That's what that option is for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is it the first close vote which throw it out of the H&I queue or the final one? That said, the UI should reflect that ([as we have discussed last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement)). I just thought [the newer answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343417/2441442) is the state of the art

Comment: Once the question is closed it is removed from the queue IIRC.

Comment: @TinyGiant Given that the CV queue doesn't even get to half of the items presented to it, and for those it does, it often takes quite some time, that's not a particularly effective solution.  If a close *vote*, rather than actual closure, removed it from the queue, then it would actually be a useful course of action.

Comment: But how often do questions flagged as VLQ actually get to a moderator? From all the posts I've read flagging a question as VLQ takes the question longer to get deleted than flagging to close it (on average), doesn't it? VLQ flags take the question to Triage (no matter where they were flagged). So the timeline could be: VLQ flag -> Triage -> Requires Editing -> 2nd VLQ flag -> Triage -> Close flag -> Close vote queue -> questions gets closed -> maybe deleted. This would be the worst case but the best case would just skip the H&I queue and go from Triage to the CVQ. On the other hand (...)

Comment: *But how often do questions flagged as VLQ actually get to a moderator?* often enough, hence my question @Keiwan

Comment: @Servy Why does the question need to be removed from the H*I? Once you skip it, it won't be served to you again.

Comment: (...) flagging to close instead of as VLQ immediately takes the question to the close vote queue. So the VLQ flag really doesn't do anything (and even works against what it's supposed to do), doesn't it?

Comment: @Servy also, what is the point of sending the question back to the triage queue? The best case scenario is that it gets sent from triage to the close vote queue. Why not just vote to close it (which puts it directly into the close vote queue) and move on?

Comment: @TinyGiant Because it means it'll be served to the next person, and if they can't remove it, then to the person after them, and the person after them.  If all of the posts that can actually be improved get removed from the queue by previous reviewers, and all of the posts that can't just stick around, then it means when you go to look at the queue you'll find yourself with 99% unreviewable items in it (even if the Triage failure rate is rather low (which it's not)).  If every HI reviewer just sees entirely unsalvageable garbage, they're likely to give up on the queue and not use it.

Comment: @Servy yeah, but there's always going to be new posts added to the queue, and someone might come along that _can_ edit it into shape, however unlikely that may be.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, but those new posts are going to make up an ever shrinking portion of the posts in the queue, if the bad posts never leave it.  It's why I didn't say the queue will become 100% crap, because it won't, it'll just get closer and closer to that point over time as both good posts and crap enter, and only good posts leave.

Comment: @Servy If everyone who sees a bad post in the H&I votes to close it, the bad posts will leave soon enough. I'm sure that there could be improvements made to how situations like this are handled. The problem I see with removing the post from the queue on the first close vote is that people close vote incorrectly all the time. As I've said elsewhere, I find most of the questions I end up answering in the close vote queue under the filter `too broad [javascript]`.

Comment: @Servy I have previously engaged in triage volleyball where I've been served the same post in the H&I three or four times in the same sitting due to the break-down in the triage queue. It's wholly pointless and the worst case scenario is that triage lets the post out into the wild with a big fat "Looks OK" sticker. The best case (but probably rarest) scenario is that triage reviews the post correctly and the post is moved to the close vote queue, which could be achieved simply by voting to close it.

Comment: @TinyGiant So you're basically just suggesting that HI become the Close Vote 2.0 review queue?  And even then you're now requiring 5 people to review the same unreviewable question (more if any of them don't have the rep to close vote, are out of close votes, or didn't realize that they're in the CV 2.0 review queue).

Comment: @TinyGiant But that's not a viable action in the HI queue.  What you're *actually* saying is that the best case scenario is that the post gets closed outside of review entirely, because the review queues that are actually supposed to close the question fail to do so.  The HI queue *can't* close it because it has no such actions.

Comment: @Servy the queues aren't perfect and reviewers are far from perfect, which is the reason why we have a questions like this pop-up a few times every week. I'm suggesting that we make the best of what we have, which means not engaging in exercises of futility and choosing the best option available to us. Sure that best option is kind of crappy, but it's the best we have.

Comment: @Servy The fact that the close vote queue is overloaded has no bearing on whether or not you should vote to close a question. Regardless of when  the question enters the close vote queue, it needs to be closed and needs to enter the close vote queue. Sending it back to triage is just pushing it down the road and keeping the question open longer, requiring yet more reviews (how many times does it need to be reviewed in triage before it actually gets sent to the close vote queue?)

Comment: @TinyGiant I never said that we should refuse to vote to close questions just because the close queue can't keep up.  I just said that it's in no way a solution to the problem, and fails to accomplish what you claim it will accomplish (removing the item from HI).  By all means, cast the close vote if you feel it's appropriate, but that still doesn't solve the problem of handling the item from the HI queue.  It's functionally identical to just saying "just click skip" from the perspective of that queue.

Comment: @Servy so if the only applicable option is to skip, what should you do? Should you choose an option that doesn't apply simply to complete the review task? Or should you step outside of the queue, perform the actions that apply to the post, then skip the review (the only applicable option)? Right now there is no real way for a single person to move a post directly from the H&I to the close vote queue, and I'm not sure there should be, given that reviewers aren't perfect and they might just be wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant Skipping isn't technically an option at all, so that's choosing to not take any action, and leave it for all of the following reviewers to have to deal with, which, if they follow your logic, they will choose to do the same, leaving a cycle that will go on for a *very* long time (basically until it ages out of the queue).  If that's all you're ever going to do you might as well just go to the CV queue instead.

Comment: @Servy actually skipping _is_ technically an option as the message sent to the server sends the option chosen as "skip" and marks the review as skipped by you. And as I said, if everyone does what I suggest here, it should only take a few reviews to close the question and remove it from the H&I. Maybe we need a "nothing to do here" button which will remove the post from the H&I if x number of users select that option, but I don't support an option that allows a single review to remove the post from the H&I and move it directly to the close vote queue.

Comment: I mean, a simple edit that fixes some grammar or formatting can do just that, but the whole polishing turds thing goes against that.

Comment: @TinyGiant It doesn't count as a review.  If you skip a post you didn't *review* it, you skipped it, and choose *not* to review it.  So no, it's *not* an action in the queue, even technically.  Like I've told you before, if everyone did what you're suggesting, then HI would be nothing but CV 2.0, and you'd be better off just going to the CV queue instead, as you'd be doing the same thing but without having to fight against the queue to do it, and no, it wouldn't just take a few people to review the items, it'd take 5 at a minimum, and likely notably more.

Comment: @Servy it does count as a review, it just doesn't count against review quotas. The system marks the review task as having been reviewed with the outcome of skip. IIRC, the system even counts the number of skips and removes the post from the queue once it has been skipped a given number of times.

Comment: @Servy so you flag it as VLQ instead, where anywhere from 3-5 reviewers have to review it again, probably incorrectly, possibly sending it back to the H&I where another user (or a few) have to review it to send it back to triage, etc, etc. All of those reviews count, and all of them would be more than if you just vote to close it and move on.

Comment: @TinyGiant That the system keeps track of the fact that you skipped the post doesn't mean it counts as a review.  The fact that there's a specific tracker of "number of items that you've reviewed" that will never change as a result of a skip tells you that, skipping an item *isn't* reviewing it.  It's choosing *not* to review it.

Comment: @Servy Semantics aside, choosing not to review a post is always an option, and a viable one at that. Sometimes it is the _only_ viable option. In which case, I would recommend choosing to skip instead of choosing another option which does not apply.

Comment: @TinyGiant So you're basically saying that you value the time of the Triage reviewers more, and think that them needing to review the item again is problematic, but having the HI reviewers have to review the same item over and over and over isn't a problem at all, even though it's not an item that HI can possibly resolve and it *is* an item that Triage can resolve?  Why is that?  Why is the Triage reviewer time so much more valuable than HI reviewer time?

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, you always have the option to not review a post.  I'm not saying that there isn't a place for that either.  Where there's a problem is if, not when a particular person not being able to review a particular post, but when *no person* could review the post (properly).  Skipping ad-infinitum isn't a suitable action in such a situation.

Comment: @Servy I maintain that if my suggestion here is followed, it would require far less reviews and be far more likely to result in the correct outcome than if everyone were to engage in triage volleyball and waste everyone's time doing something that they know will end up being a huge waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @Servy, so given you acknowledge that in such situations there is no acceptable option provided other than to skip, you would suggest that the user pick an option which is unacceptable in order to achieve a result that is extremely unlikely to come to fruition?

Comment: One more question: I am not sure how to understand [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link/288387#288387). Is the *new VLQ* flag meant to be more forgiving, but means the same as the *old one*? The only difference is, it has a chance to be turned into a close vote or disputed flag in the error case? The part I realy do not understand, why we have only the VLQ flag in first place?

Comment: @TinyGiant If we lived in an ideal world where everyone actually did exactly what we would want them to, then we wouldn't be in this situation in the first place (as Triage wouldn't be pushing bad posts to HI).  (Actually, in an even more ideal world people wouldn't ask bad questions in the first place.)  Clearly we're not in a position to talk about what people should do in a world where everyone always does what we'd want them to.

Comment: @TinyGiant `you would suggest that the user pick an option which is unacceptable in order to achieve a result that is extremely unlikely to come to fruition?` That *exact same statement* applies equally to your suggested course of action.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Shog was hoping to change what the VLQ flag means, which is why it's even an option in the HI queue in the first place.  My suggestions have been in line with Shog's proposed altered meaning of the flag.  Unfortunately, Shog was never really successful in changing the meaning of the flag, and moderators still evaluate them as they had even before that post of Shog's (and the other posts he made around the same time), which is precisely the source of the problem you're having.

Comment: @Servy the course of action I am suggesting is completely acceptable (and endorsed by shog, there was a chat convo some time ago about this very thing). Skipping is a always a viable option, and stepping out of the queue to act on a question is always a viable option. I am suggesting that users use the _only_ acceptable options available in cases like this.

Comment: @TinyGiant But the only acceptable option is itself not an acceptable option, as it results in all of the bad items sitting around, never leaving the queue, meaning that HI reviewers need to either sift through piles and piles of crap just to find a post worth reviewing, or they need to polish the crap (which you're making, by far, the path of least resistance as a reviewer, meaning that's where things are going to end up).

Comment: @Servy I honestly cannot see the H&I becoming a massive pile of crap (any more than it already is) if everyone who sees the crap votes to close it as such and moves on. Regardless, choosing an unacceptable option that routinely leads to flag bans is never going to be a good idea.

Comment: "Also keep in mind that only moderators can decline flags." — this is not true of anything except spam/offensive flags. Closure flags can be declined by unanimous Leave Open votes. VLQ/NAA flags on answers can be declined if there aren't enough recommendations/votes for deletion. On other SE sites, VLQ flags on questions can be declined similarly if there aren't enough recommendations/votes for closures. And as far as I know, the only way to get a disputed flag from Triage is if the outcome was not unanimous — admittedly very common *if* flagging from Triage itself, but if flagged from H&I?