# How to handle identified spam in Help and Improvement

Tags: discussion, spam, help-improvement

We have had a long discussion about the problem in the H&I-Queue here, because we can not take the actions we want to take. For example [this here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement).

Now the system said:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

[image: Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully]

Which Action would be appropriate, if the content would be indeed spam? (which it is not in the current case)

I only see [Edit] and [Skip]. A little bit hidden also [VLQ] (Which it is not, it would be simple spam. [And I don't risk another ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346020/what-is-the-official-moderator-statement-about-low-quality-flags-in-the-help-and)).

- Is this message a bug? According to the current explanations on other questions, a spam question should never be moved to H&I.
- If not, how are we supposed to process the situation **without pressing *[skip]* and open the question in a new tab**?

I want to process the queue to reduce the backlog.

Comment: That message is mostly an indicator for a review audit, so just apply some common sense and you'll be fine. Now about the general question: if a question really is spam and had moved its way to H&I, then flag that question as spam if you also agree that it is spam (open the question outside of the queue) or if unsure, skip it. Help and Improvement is still a "vague" queue, because the Triage reviewers keep choosing the wrong review button (i.e "requires editing" instead of "unsalvageable").

Comment: Also that "VLQ"  link feels a bit like a trap. It is appropriate for some kind of question, but if you have a question that is suitable for closing (like "too broad" or "requests off-site resources") then, VLQ can result in a declined/disputed flag, although your general sense is correct). So open the question in a new tab, vote to close and skip the review.

Comment: @Tom if it's spam and it arrived to the H&I queue, that means that we need to ban 3 to 5 triage reviewers.

Comment: @Braiam I totally agree with you. The Triage queue is mostly the reason why I can't do much in the H&I queue. Most of the questions there or unsalvageable.

Comment: @Tom this won't kick it out of review. My main motivation is, that the system ask me to do something, that I am not able to do nativly. Hence my previously feature-request. (Which seems to be ignored, but on the other site the developers give me messages, as this feature-request would be perfectly valid)

Comment: Yes I saw your feature request and already supported it with an upvote. I've done several reviews in that queue and skipped most of them, because most questions shouldn't be in that queue. A more clear explanation about the correct action in the "Triage" queue hasn't been implemented, yet. So I would say, keep skipping, although it feels false, but still open that question in a new Browser tab and flag it (or vote to close) appropriately. If that question got closed, it should be gone from H&I (but I'm not quite sure about that).

Comment: @Tom How do you apply common sense to a review which says "this is probably spam, do you want to skip it or edit it?" It rather seems to me that the lack of common sense by the person who made the review is the problem here...

Comment: @Lundin Common sense says that you still don't choose options that don't make any sense, and it says go look for better options if you can. "Skip" just means, "I'm not going to do anything with this via the review queue."

Comment: @jpmc26 My point here is, when the only option given is to edit, why does the review system even whine about spam? This is clearly a design mistake of this review queue.

Comment: @Lundin That the review queue doesn't make sense is a separate issue from, "What do I do about this post in the review queue?" though. That kind of analysis belongs in the feature request. You can still apply your common sense to make the best of an illogical situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to perform an action not available in a review, you click the link to get to the actual post, take the action you want, and press Skip. If you don't want to do that, then press Skip and admit you're being a little lazy.

The fact it shouldn't be in the queue in the first place does nothing to change what the correct action *now* is. It's there. Do what you can about it. Don't wring your hands over it.

This doesn't negate the need for good options in the review queues, but it's the obvious and straightforward solution given the options you have. If you don't like the way the review queues work, don't review in them. (There's stuff like [Fire Alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6373379/firealarm) and [Smoke Detector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector) in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you still want to help clean up stuff.)